# How to fix "External file changes sync may be slow: The current inotify(7) watch limit is too low." in PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Been trying to research what this error "External file changes sync may be slow: The current inotify(7) watch limit is too low." means and how to fix it in PhpStorm but I seem not to be able to get around it. The message pops up every time I run PhpStorm. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try increasing the `max_user_watches` values and see if that fixes your issue. Open `/etc/sysctl.conf` with root permissions and change the `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` number to a bigger one.

```sh
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

After modifying and saving the file, run `sudo sysctl -p` to apply the changes. Re-open PhpStorm and verify if the warning is gone.

Comment: How do I open /etc/sysctl.conf 
please?

Comment: What OS are you using? Usually you can just `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`. You can also use `subl` or `code` or `gedit` instead of `nano`.

Comment: Linux mint, I've used the first option but I don't have `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` after openning  All I'm getting some codes with some options at the bottom e.g `^G Get Help  ^O Write Out ^W Where Is  ^K Cut Text`

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of the file and add the line. Then save it and run `sudo sysctl -p`.

Answer (score 2):

[JetBrains recommendations](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/IDEA-A-2/Inotify-Watches-Limit-Linux) for this is to increase system file watch limit.

In Debian-based Linux distros best practice is to keep local kernel params changes in a separate file:

```bash
echo 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches=32768' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/90-jetbrains.conf
sudo sysctl --system
```

This will prevent config conflicts at system upgrade.